Make the next/prev elements take up 50% of the viewport each
I have a carousel that I want to go to the previous or next when clicked, depending on the position of the pointer.
Currently I have to go to the next one by clicking on the carousel, but I don't know how to do what was indicated above and which I also explain in the illustration below:

I currently have the following, which as I explained previously, clicking the carousel advances to the next one:
function goToNextCarouselPage() {    
   var $next = $dots.filter('.active').next();

   if (!$next.length)
      $next = $dots.first();

   $next.trigger('click');
            }   
   $('.owl-item').click(function () {
      goToNextCarouselPage();   
   });

Any idea how to do it? I thank you in advance for any collaboration.

Make the next/prev elements take up 50% of the viewport each.
